# Localization of the ideal of some projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, localization

> Let $X \subset P^n$ be some projective variety, and $I$ be its ideal.
>   We consider the 0th graded piece of the localization $(I \cdot
> k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0$ in the coordinate ring
>   $(k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0 \cong k[z_1,...,z_n]$. This is exactly
>   the ideal of the affine open subset $X\cap A^n \subset A^n$.

I cannot understand why the 0th graded piece of the localization $(I \cdot
k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0$ in the coordinate ring
$(k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0 \cong k[z_1,...,z_n]$ is exactly
the ideal of the affine open subset $X\cap A^n \subset A^n$. (specifically, I do not know why this is called *localization*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isomorphism $(k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0 \cong k[z_1,...,z_n]$ is just the dehomogenization with respect to $Z_i$. Each $F\in I$ of degree $r$, corresponds to $F/Z_i^r \in (I \cdot k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0$, hence corresponds to its dehomogenization with respect to $Z_i$.

$k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}]$ is the localization of the ring k[Z_0,...,Z_n] with respect to the multiplicative set $\{1, Z_i, Z_i^2, \dots \}$. This is a basic construction of Commutative Algebra.

Comment: In fact I know why $(k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0 \cong k[z_1,...,z_n]$. But I cannot understand what is $(I \cdot
k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0$

Comment: $I \cdot k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}]$ is the ideal generated by $F/Z_i^k$ where $F\in I$ homogeneous and $k$ is arbitrary. Now choose the elements that have zero degree ;)

Comment: So It seems we can simply write this as $(I \cdot k[Z_i^{-1}])_0$. Why bother to be $(I \cdot k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}])_0$ ?

Comment: Because its elements are polynomials in $Z_0, \dots, Z_n$ and in $1/Z_i$.

Comment: But  $(I \cdot k[Z_i^{-1}])_0$ still contains $Z_0,...,Z_n$ and  $Z_i^{-1}$

Comment: I think, maybe, the point is because $k[Z_i^{-1}]$ is not an ideal ? Since it is more comfortable when we deal with an ideal.

Comment: $I \cdot k[Z_i^{-1}]$ doesn't even make sense. We have inclusions $I \subset  k[Z_0,...,Z_n] \subset  k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}]$ and the ideal $I \cdot k[Z_0,...,Z_n,Z_i^{-1}]$ is the ideal generated by $I$ in the last ring.

Comment: I suggest you to take a crash course on commutative algebra. It is not hard to read the following: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Commutative-Algebra-Addison-Wesley-Mathematics/dp/0201407515

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.